# Set VARCHAR size in view column

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, group-by

Hitting an issue when using the below SQL code to create a view.

The columns that are created for `property_changed` and `property_values` are default set to the size of the outermost CONCAT.

This becomes an issue when using the columns later on in code where I would need the columns to be current-string + 50 more chars.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  \`my_view\` AS
        select *,
            CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"', table.property_name, '"')), ']') AS property_changed,
            CONCAT('[',
                    GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('old_value', old_value, 'new_value', new_value)),
                    ']'
                ) AS property_values
        
        from table_log table
group by id, p_o_id, p_o_v, date_created, name, e_name
```

I have tried using MySQL CAST in all different ways, but the code fails every time.
Is there something in here that stops me from using CAST(.... AS VARCHAR(300) ?

Or is there another way of achieving this that I haven't realized?

Comment: This is not valid (standard) SQL. You have `select *`, aggregation functions (`group_concat()`), and no `group by` clause. What are you trying to do? Sample data and desired results may help here.

Comment: Added `group by`, left it out before since I thought it was out of scope. What I am to do is copy and table, and add two new columns.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes it look like you are trying to generate JSON arrays. If so, and provided that you are running MySQL 5.7.22 or higher, don't use string concatenation functions: MySQL offers `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` for that purpose.

This is simpler, more efficient and safer (as an example, MySQL handles the escaping for you if some of your values contain embedded double quotes).

```
select id, p_o_id, p_o_v, date_created, name, e_name,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(property_name) AS property_changed,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('old_value', old_value, 'new_value', new_value)) AS property_values
from table_log table
group by id, p_o_id, p_o_v, date_created, name, e_name
```

This generates columns of `JSON` datatype, not strings - which seems more relevant here.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I am at a lower version, so this didn't work for me. But, setting the `group_concat_max_len` to a higher value solved the issue for me.